# Using Different Hibernate Version In A Dependency Depending on the Target

Tags: maven

I'm hoping someone could point me in the right direction here. I think it's simplest to give an example of the issue I ran into.

I have a maven project that I'd like to use in two different applications.

The project `MyProj` has a dependency on Hibernate. I've included it as a dependency for a Wildfly server project `WildflyProj` and a Liferay project `LiferayProj`.

This worked fine until we upgraded Wildfly, which came with a new version of Hibernate.

To use `MyProj` with `WildflyProj`, I must change the Hibernate dependency in `MyProj` to Hibernate 5. However to continue using `MyProj` with `LiferayProj`, I need to hold `MyProj` back to Hibernate 4. `MyProj` works with either version without any code changes.

As a workaround, I now have two branches of `MyProj` that need to be maintained with different versions of Hibernate.

Is there a better strategy I can use?

I have *build* projects for both `WildflyProj` and `LiferayProj` that build all required projects in order.

i.e.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project..>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.com/groupId>
        <artifactId>project-management</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.3</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>WildflyProj</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Builds WildflyProj and Dependencies</name>

    <modules>
        <module>../MyProj</module>
        <module>../AnotherProj</module>
        <module>../WildflyProj</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

There's no way I can override the hibernate version in the `MyProj` module here, is there?

I assume this can't be a very rare problem, so there must be a simple solution I'm unaware of.